# How do I add a second dataset to a dotplot in R?

Tags: r, plot, charts, dot

I've just started learning R in a statistics course and started learning the different plots.

One exercise requires us to plot two groups of data into a dot-plot, but I'm struggling to add the second group of data to it. I'm using the dotplot() function, and the two data groups are vectors (I think).

I'm not entirely sure on the lingo yet, so please bear with me.

```
smokers <- c(69.3, 56.0, 22.1, 47.6, 53.2, 48.1, 52.7, 34.4, 60.2, 43.8, 23.2, 13.8)
nonsmokers <- c(28.6, 25.1, 26.4, 34.9, 29.8, 28.4, 38.5, 30.2, 30.6, 31.8, 41.6, 21.1, 36.0, 37.9, 13.9)

dotplot(smokers, col = "blue", pch = 19)

points(nonsmokers, col = "red", pch = 18)
```

The result is a dotplot of the smoker-data, but the red points for nonsmokers aren't added to the plot.

How do I add the points to the plot, or are there better ways to do it?

**PS. The two groups must be on the same line according to the problem.**

Edit 1: This is the lattice package. I'd loaded it on another script and forgot.

Comment: Are you using the `dotplot` function from the lattice package? Or something else? It would be helpful if you include the `library` statement in your code so that we know.

Comment: Yes this is from the lattice package. I'd loaded it earlier and forgot.

Comment: Do you want both lines of dots together, or on separate lines?

Comment: The exercise says the dots for the two groups must be on the same line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively to the use of `lattice` package, you can wrap your two vectors into a single dataframe and plot them using `ggplot2`:

```r
df <- data.frame(Value = c(smokers,nonsmokers),
                 Cat = c(rep("smokers",length(smokers)), rep("nonsmokers",length(nonsmokers))),
                 xseq = c(seq_along(smokers),seq_along(nonsmokers)))
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x = Cat, y = Value, color = Cat)) + geom_point()+xlab("")
```

[image]

**EIT: Plotting two groups on a single line**

If you want to have both group on a single line you can do:

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x = "points", y = Value, color = Cat)) + geom_point()+xlab("")
```

[image]

Is it what you are looking for ?

Comment: Wow this is definitely a better way to present the data! Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately the problem specifically says that the points must all be on the same and I haven't found a way to do that yet.

Comment: `seq(1:length(smokers))` doesn't need `seq`. A better way is `seq_along(smokers)`, it avoids the case when `length(smokers) == 0`.

Comment: What a dumb !! ... you're right @RuiBarradas-ReinstateMonic, I'm correcting it right now.

Comment: @Esye, I edited my answer to plot all points on a single line. Does it look what you are expecting?

Comment: This is what I wanted! Thank you very much!

Comment: @dc37 just out of curiosity, what does col = Cat do?

Comment: `color = Cat` will tell to ggplot2 to colored points according to their value in the column `Cat` which is either `smokers` or `nonsmokers`. That's why you get the legend added to the left. Glad my answer helps you.

Comment: Ah I see. Does it have to be named Cat, or could it be anything?

Comment: It has to be named according the name you give to the categorical column in your dataframe. For more informations, you can read: http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Colors_(ggplot2)/

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to combine the data and use a formula as the argument to `dotplot()`.

```
smokers <- c(69.3, 56.0, 22.1, 47.6, 53.2, 48.1, 52.7, 34.4, 60.2, 43.8, 23.2, 13.8)
nonsmokers <- c(28.6, 25.1, 26.4, 34.9, 29.8, 28.4, 38.5, 30.2, 30.6, 31.8, 41.6, 21.1, 36.0, 37.9, 13.9)
library(lattice)
df1 <- data.frame(value=smokers)
df1$group <- "smokers"
df2 <- data.frame(value=nonsmokers)
df2$group = "nonsmokers"
data <- rbind(df1,df2)
dotplot(value ~ group, data = data)
```

...and the output:

[image]

To use group to distinguish the groups by color, we use the following form of `dotplot()`.

```
aKey <- simpleKey(c("smokers","nonsmokers"))
dotplot(data$value,groups = data$group,key = aKey)
```

...and the output:

[image]

Comment: This is probably the best way to do it. The problem tells us to put all points on one line though, but I'm starting to think it's pointless and better to just do it like this instead...

Comment: @Esye - check my latest update, which uses a different form of syntax to use group as a color variable.

Comment: @Eyse - and to print the key that associates the colors with the values of group, one must use the `simpleKey()` function to create the key.

Comment: @Eyse - so do you have to solve the problem with the lattice package, or can you use the ggplot2 solution? If you're going to be working with lattice, it's worth some time to review the package documentation so you can understand how to embellish the charts with appropriate labels and titles. The same applies to ggplot2, as it is also a relatively complex package.

Comment: What package we use doesn't really matter. I just happened to use Lattice on a former task and used it again. I'm looking into ggplot2 now.